# What does "mplaceholder" refer to in android developer "Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread"?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am working with bitmaps and trying to follow the guidliness provided in android developer site. I have followed all the steps in detail however i am stuck with a parameter passed in the following method.

```
    public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), **mPlaceHolderBitmap**, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) is the link that i am following. And I am storing and retrieving images from sqlite database however that is not a problem.

Comment: sorry it is actually "mplaceholderBitmap"